# How to Preselect Component Template

Tags: templating, component

We are using Tridion Site 9.6.

if we are adding Component into page, if we have only 1 component Template for component, it will be selecting automatically. but if we have multiple CT's for same component, by default its not selecting any option.

few users are creating Pages with out selecting CT and Publishing fails lack of CT. How to set any one Teamplate pre selected on CT dropdown or how to add required condition before adding into page. need to fix this scenario on Classic UI / New UI as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's nothing out of the box for this yet.

You could look at a GUI extension, but two points spring to mind:

1. GUI extensions for NEW UI are not available in 9.6, although they will be available for development in 10.0
2. Unless the Component was always to be displayed with a specific CT you won't totally mitigate the issue of user error and the user just accepting whatever your logic "suggests".

You could look at an Event to check, say on Page PreSave and check if any CPs are missing CTs and raise an exception; of course, you should consider if there will be scenarios (in the future) where you will want allow CPs on a page without a specific CT.

Comment: Thanks for update. Do we have any code sample for Page PreSave to validate CT's